# Angular.js .push creates a new ng-repeat instead of appending new data to main div

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a "load more" functionality using Angular, but when I click "load more", a new ng-repeat div is being created rather than appending data to existing div. I couldn't understand why it's happening. I tried both loadMore.data and loadMore.data[0]. While `loadMore.data[0]` works, it creates a new ng-repeat. `loadMore.data` doesn't work at all, it creates an empty div.

ui-router stuff

```
angular.module('site.feed.routes')
.run(
  ['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
      $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    }
  ]
)

.config(
  ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

      $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
      });

      $stateProvider
        .state('posttest', {
          url: '/post1',
          templateUrl: 'view.html',
          resolve: {
            data: 'PostData',
          },
          controller: 'PostController'
        });
    }
  ]
);
```

Factory

```
angular.module('site.feed').factory('PostData', ["$http", function($http) {
  return {
    getPage: function(pageNumber) {
      return $http.get('/feed/' + pageNumber);
    }
  };      
}]);
```

Controller

```
angular.module('site.feed').controller('PostController', ['$scope', 'data', 'PostData', function($scope, data, PostData) {
  $scope.page = 0;
  $scope.data = data; // first page

  if ($scope.page === 0) {
    PostData.getPage(1).then(function(returned) {
      $scope.data = returned.data;
      $scope.page++;
    });
  }

  $scope.incr = function() {
    $scope.page++;
    PostData.getPage($scope.page).then(function(loadMore) {
      //console.log($scope.data);
      $scope.data.push(loadMore.data[0]);
    });
  };
}]);
```

View

```
<div ng-repeat="feedflow in data">
  <div ng-repeat="ehe in feedflow.feed">
    {{feedflow.id}}
    {{ehe.status}}
  </div>
</div>

<button ng-click="incr()">load next page</button>
```

Comment: So you only want to push on the feedflow.feed?

Comment: @Louie Almeda, When I click the button, new data is being added to my page but in a new ng-repeat div, not into the existing one.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can reproduce this on a plunkr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

I was adding the new data as a new array rather than adding items into the existing array.

Here's a revised version of incr()

```
$scope.incr = function() {
    $scope.page++;
    PostData.getPage($scope.page).then(function(returned2) {
      //$scope.data[0].feed.push(returned2.data[0].feed);
      var len = returned2.data[0].feed.length;
      console.log(len);
      for (var pp = 0; pp < len; pp++) {
        $scope.data[0].feed.push(returned2.data[0].feed[pp]);
      }
    });
  };
```